# PowerShell error has full SOAP Response not the contents

Tags: powershell, soap, invoke-webrequest

I'm calling an SOAP API.  PowerShell is giving an error and the error contains the response I am expecting! Whereas the contents of the variable I'm sending the response to is missing some data.

```bsh
[xml]$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $UserURI -Method POST -ContentType "test/xml;charset=utf-8" -Body $input

$SOAPResponse = [xml]$response.Content
```

PowerShell is returning:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns1="https://test.safetylearning.co.uk/api/1.3/UserManagement">
<SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:AddUserResponse><AddUserResult><errorcode>500</errorcode>
<description>Error</description><errors><item><id>52001</id><description>Unable
to add one or more users.</description></item><item><id>52010</id>
<description>User with ID ['9991'] fails</description></item><item><id>0</id>
<description>A user identified by ID ['9991'] exists</description></item>
</errors></AddUserResult></ns1:AddUserResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
At C:\Temp\Delme3.ps1:37 char:18
+ ... $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $UserURI -Method POST -ContentType ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

So I can see the error I want i.e. A user identified by ID ['9991'] exists. However

```bsh
$SOAPResponse.Envelope.Body.AddUserResponse.AddUserResult.errors
```

returns nothing!

```bsh
$SOAPResponse.Envelope.Body.FirstChild.InnerXml
```

returns:

```xml
<AddUserResult><errorcode>200</errorcode><description>OK</description><errors /></AddUserResult>
```

`<errors>` is empty!

SOAPUI gives the correct error:

```xml
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="https://test.safetylearning.co.uk/api/1.3/UserManagement">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:AddUserResponse>
         <AddUserResult>
            <errorcode>500</errorcode>
            <description>Error</description>
            <errors>
               <item>
                  <id>52001</id>
                  <description>Unable to add one or more users.</description>
               </item>
               <item>
                  <id>52010</id>
                  <description>User with ID ['9999'] fails</description>
               </item>
               <item>
                  <id>0</id>
                  <description>A user identified by ID ['9999'] exists</description>
               </item>
            </errors>
         </AddUserResult>
      </ns1:AddUserResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Can you add the full `$response.Content` to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the request in a Try/Catch and reference the $error[0].ErrorDetails in the Catch block. That specific user error would be returned with the following Catch block:

```
try {
[xml]$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $UserURI -Method POST -ContentType "test/xml;charset=utf-8" -Body $input
$SOAPResponse = [xml]$response.Content
$SOAPResponse
]

catch {
[xml]$errResponse = $error[0].ErrorDetails
$errCode = $errResponse.Envelope.body.AddUserResponse.AddUserResult.errors.ChildNodes[2].description
$errCode
}
```

That block would output the valid SOAP response, or just the error code buried in that SOAP envelope from the error

```
$errResponse.Envelope.body.AddUserResponse.AddUserResult.errors.ChildNodes[2].description
A user identified by ID ['9991'] exists
```